# Plot point changing color depending on z-value

Tags: pgfplots

I want something like a heat map, where plot points with height 0 appear blue, with height 1 red and everything inbetween I want a fade of colors.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot3[red,only marks]
        {e^(-pi * 50^(-2) * (x^2 + y^2))};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, you already have been asked twice to post a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and not a snippet like you did three times now. Please consider doing this from now on and maybe have a look to this website rules.

Comment: @kerf Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: That's much better, but there's lots of information about heat maps in TikZ.  Have you tried looking through that?

Comment: @Teepeemm I did, but for my case there are unfortunatly not many examples :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: red-blue colormap]

Code below is slightly modified from `pgfplots` manual's equivalence for `winter`. Look at 'surface' or `surf` for ways to adjust the output further.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/colormap={redblue}{rgb255=(0,0,255) rgb255=(255,0,0)}
}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot3[surf]
        {e^(-pi * 50^(-2) * (x^2 + y^2))};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

if you don't want a fading which fills the surface, but only to colour the `marks` with colours from the `colormap`, you can use `only marks,scatter` in place of `surf`:

[image: marks/scatter rather than surface fill]

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your help! My problem is now, that by using \addplot3[only marks] I have a discrete set of plot dots and I want those dots to be colored and not the whole graph of the function

Comment: @kerf How is that a fade? Do you mean you want the colours of the points to be the colours they would be if the surface did use a fading? This isn't really my area, so I may just misunderstand the terms involved.

Comment: @kerf If that's a correct interpretation, see edit above. I have to say, the result looks rather strange to me. The `marks` don't look as if they are in the correct depth order.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks! You are right, this instance looks a little bit weird, but with smaller dots and larger sample size (my actual version) it looks alright :)